# How do I map all properties of a value object to 1 string column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Assume I have a `Person` entity class which has an `Address` property.

```
public class Person
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

        public class Address
        {
            public Address(string address)
            {
                // Retrieve the fields from a string
            }

            public string Street { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Street}; no. {Number}";
            }
        }
```

So far I've tried this:

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
{
    builder
        .OwnsOne(x => x.Address, a =>
        {
            a.WithOwner();

            a.Property(y => y.Street);
            a.Property(y => y.Number);
        });

    base.Configure(builder);
}
```

This will map both `Address.Street` and `Address.Number` to their own column inside `Person`'s table (respectively *Address_Street* and *Address_Number*).

I want to map all `Address` properties in `Person`'s table as 1 column of type string and make it has the value as described in its `ToString()` method and be constructed back from the saved string as described in the constructor.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What happens if you modify this concatinated field in your database? You can use computed columns or views in your db if you want such a column.

Comment: @Michael I should never modify this concatinated field in my database. For the sake of this question we can assume all the invariants and inconsistencies are being treated by the application.

Comment: In my experience whenever there's a chance of storing primitive data, that opportunity should gratefully be embraced. Storing processed data is a form of data loss. OK, it's not likely, but a street or name *could* contain the string "; no.". More likely is that one day the formatting convention may change, requiring all fields to be updated. So my advice: store the fields separately and add a computed field that returns the formatted string.

Comment: @GertArnold what do you mean by computed field?

Comment: AKA computed column: https://database.guide/what-is-a-computed-column-in-sql-server/

Comment: Can also be done with code first approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns (new in EF Core 5)

Comment: @GertArnold Okay I'll follow your suggestion, but just for the sake of knowledge: what I asked is even possible assuming EF Core?

Comment: If it is, then could you submit an answer along with the suggestion of not storing computed data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience whenever there's a chance of storing primitive data, that opportunity should gratefully be embraced. Storing processed data is a form of data loss. OK, it's not likely, but a street or name could contain the string "; no.". More likely is that one day the formatting convention may change, requiring all fields to be updated. So my advice: store the fields separately and add a [computed column](https://database.guide/what-is-a-computed-column-in-sql-server/) that returns the formatted string. This can also be done in [code-first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns).

For academic purposes: yes it can be done using [value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions). The idea is to convert an `Address` to the string to be stored and, conversely, the stored string to an `Address` object, I simplified your case a little bit and shamelessly omitted all kinds of validation/exception handling:

The classes:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Address(string address)
    {
        var parts = address.Split(";");
        Street = parts[0];
        Number = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Street};{Number}";
    }
}
```

The mapping:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(p => p.Address)
        .HasConversion(address => address.ToString(), 
                       str => new Address(str));
}
```

Note that `Address` now is a class that's not part of EF's model.

Answer (score 2):

For interested readers and for educational purposes I provide an answer with calculated columns.
As already said: Storing this field as a concatinated string in a relational database violates one of the most fundamental design patterns: fields have to be atomic.

In SQLite (and other database systems) we can define *computed columns*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Persons" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Address_Street TEXT NOT NULL,
    Address_Number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Address_Text AS ([Address_Street] || '; no. ' || [Address_Number])
);
```

Since EF Core 5 we are able to define this column in code first:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DemoApp
{
    public class Person
    {
        private Person() { }                              // Constructor for EF Core

        public Person(Address address)
        {
            Address = address;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }               // Database generated by convention
        public Address Address { get; set; } = default!;  // Value object; nullable forgivng if you enable nullable.
        public string AddressText { get; } = default!;    // Our computed property (read only) nullable forgivng if you enable nullable.
    }

    // C# 9 records provides equality based on all values and they are immutable.
    // If you want to update person, you have to reassign a new instance.
    // Positional syntax for property definition
    public record Address(
        [property: MaxLength(255)] string Street,
        int Number
    );

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons => Set<Person>();

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("DataSource = MyDatabase.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(p => p.Address);
            // SQL expressions can be database specific (string concatenation with || or +). So we use this
            // expression only for SQLite.
            if (Database.IsSqlite())
            {
                // Address is a value object, so street and number will be mapped to Address_Street
                // and Address_Number in the person table. Therefore we have to define this
                // as a property of person.
                modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                    .Property(p => p.AddressText)
                    .HasComputedColumnSql("[Address_Street] || '; no. ' || [Address_Number]");
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                // Creates
                // INSERT INTO "Persons" ("Address_Number", "Address_Street")
                //    VALUES(@p0, @p1);
                context.Persons.Add(new Person(new Address("My Street", 10)));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                // Creates
                // SELECT "p"."AddressText" FROM "Persons" AS "p" LIMIT 1
                //
                // Output: My Street; no. 10
                Console.WriteLine(context.Persons.Select(p => p.AddressText).First());
            }
        }
    }
}
```